# Can you use OKhttp to respond with a 200 Or is it only to setup to send requests

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

i created a okhttp post request and now i wanted to respond to that post with a 200. from what it looks like i dont see anything saying i can and i need to find another libary to respond back. Looking i think i might use http4k but i want to be 100% sure.

Comment: Who are you making a request _against_? Do you own both the client and the server? It would be highly unusual for a single process to make an HTTP request against _itself_. Is the server also Kotlin?